# Регулярка на vbscript для sql запроса

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения, vbscript

Есть данные вида:

```
849591":"D139888907960162"W","76561198306866","ul":"XH5ApeknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpZAJA7cW5moWfqPv7IE_2b6T9tvw2FG3_UcYPBdwVraVu2-15eBmnVl7z5iuyjsDymLt,"m":"имя_1","n:"netore,"t":"k","p":цена_1,"s:],"":10851801",{"84946454","D112565269884","W","b","m":"имя_2",tmvHYjsSre":","p":цена_2,"],"13982816",{"i84992193","028189599611207","by":"765611006866","ul":"XH5YQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgLQJf2PLacDBA5ciJlY20k_jkI7fUhFR--NshtibkcvtybnmrjlbhjdreUd1drYFnR_QK2x73qg5G-uczMyntmvHYjsSrezhbh0wY1gghbdtn","m":"имя_3","0pqMjr0Ipoan sa"H5YQkk","p":цена_3,"s":[],"wl":"3
```

Нужные мне данные **имя** и **цена**. Их можно получить регуляркой для двух переменных:

**цена**

```
"p":(.*?),
```

**имя**

```
"m":"(.*?)"
```

либо сразу

```
"m":"(.*?)".*?"p":(.*?),
```

Мне нужно запихнуть эти данные в **sql** запрос вида *INSERT INTO `test_table` VALUES ('имя', 'цена', NOW());*

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User id=root;password=test_pwd;database=test_db")
 Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Try
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
         cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `test_table` VALUES ('имя', 'цена', NOW());"
End Try
```

Но вот правильно оформить на vbscript у меня не выходит :(

Comment: Версию MySQL озвучьте - в данном случае это важно. А вместо NOW() надо было правильно прописать дефолтное значение поля даты-времени.

Comment: Версия MySQL 5.5. Кстати дефолтное значение столбца data datetime NOT NULL, его получается можно не заполнять командой NOW()?

Comment: Версия 5,5 - Вам не повезло... старовата. Придётся руками парсить. А дефолтного значения поле с такой дефиницией не имеет. Надо изменить на *`data` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*